# How to implement fold right for Tree in purescript

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purescript

I am new to Purescript so I was trying to implement fold left and fold right (aka reduce) for my custom Tree data structure, but I am having problem implementing logic for fold right:

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance foldableTree :: Foldable Tree where
    foldl f d (Node left right) = foldl f (foldl f d left) right
    foldl f d (Leaf a) = f (d) (a)
    foldr f d (Node left right) = ???
    foldr f d (Leaf a) = ???
```

I only got so far with implementation:

```hs
instance foldableTree :: Foldable Tree where
    foldl f d (Node left right) = foldl f (foldl f d left) right
    foldl f d (Leaf a) = f (d) (a)
    foldr f d (Node left right) = f (foldr f d left) (foldr f d right)
    foldr f d (Leaf a) = a
```

But this implementation is flawed because deafult value is not passed to the fold

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know how to implement logic for fold right using Depth first traversal

Comment: Can you describe the logic that you want to implement in words? Did you implement `foldl` yourself, do you understand what it does? Did you make an attempt at implementing `foldr`? At least the base case should be trivial. Try spelling out the types of all involved terms, it usually helps tremendously.

Comment: @Bergi I did implement foldl myself, I attempted to implement foldr but I don't know how to implement it so that default value is passed when traversal is finished

Comment: "*when traversal is finished*" might be a red herring

Comment: "*default value is not passed to the fold*" - yes indeed. Can you change the implementation for `Leaf a` to use the default value?

Comment: Hint: use the same approach you used for `foldl`

Comment: Btw, `f (foldr f d left) (foldr f d right)` doesn't seem to typecheck

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I only needed to use same logic as on fold left but with swapped arguments for Leaf and for the recursive function "foldr" by first providing right side then left side:

```hs
instance foldableTree :: Foldable Tree where
    foldl f d (Node left right) = foldl f (foldl f d left) right
    foldl f d (Leaf a) = f d a
    foldr f d (Node left right) = foldr f (foldr f d right) left
    foldr f d (Leaf a) = f a d
```

Comment: https://try.purescript.org/?code=LYewJgrgNgpgBAERqOB3AFjATjAsAKAIEtgAHELAF0QENKaA6AMRCjBoCNY4AKAYyg0AzkLgs2nWABo4AM1ZgoM%2BWyzKFAWRqkksmtEoAZAJQEC7enAAqOeDTgBeOIZg1ZcewB84AOXDweGxg7Y14gkLN8IgA7IXpovngVdi4YcLgALgyxBUl4dIxsPHw4UrkFKDk4MF4-MHhYWWosIgBzdEpQp2TK9x4eqprGzrgW9soCMvK2XureFzcPLqqeMFCeGlMSsuSsQdr-OGHRto7l3ZWL9xqxs6OYJsmdhT3r%2Bdd3Tccq%2BzAn0uSWlI30B2l0%2BigRgIQA